# How do I test an AngularJS directive with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, jasmine

I just look for all tutorials, but don't understand why my service doesn't behave on directive.

Help me please to test this directive:

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive 'metaForPrerender', [
  'MetaFactory'
  '$compile'
  (MetaFactory, $compile) ->

    restrict: "EA",
    link: (scope) ->
      if MetaFactory.statusCode
        html = '<meta content="{{statusMetaCode}}"></meta>'
        if MetaFactory.statusCode == '301'
          html += '<meta content="{{statusMetaLocation}}"></meta>'
        angular.element('head').append($compile(html)(scope));
        scope.statusMetaCode = MetaFactory.statusCode
        scope.statusMetaLocation = MetaFactory.statusLocation

]
```

My service:

```
angular.module('app.services').factory 'MetaFactory', ->
  statusCode: "",
  statusLocation: ""
```

Here is my Jasmine test:

```
element = null
scope = null

beforeEach(module('app.services'))

beforeEach inject ($rootScope, $compile) ->
  scope = $rootScope.$new()
  element = angular.element(
    '<head meta_for_prerender></head>')
  $compile(element)(scope)

describe 'MetaFactory', ->
  it 'properly injected', inject((MetaFactory) ->
    expect(MetaFactory.statusCode).toBe('')
    expect(MetaFactory.statusLocation).toBe('')
  )

describe 'metaForPrerender', ->
  it 'get right scope in directive', inject((MetaFactory) ->
    MetaFactory.statusCode = 301
    MetaFactory.statusLocation = 'NewYork'

    scope.$digest()

    expect(element.text()).toBe('<meta content="301"></meta><meta content="NewYork"></meta>')
  )
```

As you see my service injected well but look likes directive ignore this service and variables inside.